# Remove Y Axis Sorting on DevExpress Chart (WinForms)

Tags: c#, winforms, sorting, charts, devexpress

I have DevExpress ChartControl and by default the Chart is sorted on Y Axis, but I don't want that behavior. I need the ChartControl to show the datasource the way I build it.

[image: Chart control]

The chart is sorted on Y-Axis (3010139, 3010136, 3010129, ...). But, it's not the way my List was sorted, and I want to remove this behavior from my chartcontrol.

[Link to C# Code](http://pastie.org/private/dyw2kh1xfedlq938dnpq7q)

Comment: can you post the xaml definition of your ChartControl and the data you use as datasource for the chart?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should set either the [ChartControl.SeriesSorting](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraChartsChartControl_SeriesSortingtopic) property value or the  [SeriesBase.SeriesPointsSorting](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraChartsChartControl_SeriesSortingtopic) property value to  `DevExpress.XtraCharts.SortingMode.None`.

For more details please refer to [Sorting Data](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument6173) help article.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [AxisBase.QualitativeScaleComparer](https://documentation.devexpress.com/CoreLibraries/DevExpress.XtraCharts.AxisBase.QualitativeScaleComparer.property) property to define a custom axis label order (see the sample code snippet from the [How to: Display Qualitative Scale Values Sorted in a Custom Sort Order](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/115144/controls-and-libraries/chart-control/examples/creating-charts/data-representation/how-to-display-qualitative-scale-values-sorted-in-a-custom-sort-order) article).

The main idea is to attach a class instance implementing the [System.Collections.IComparer interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.icomparer?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8) to sort axis values.

See also: [How to use the IComparable and IComparer interfaces in Visual C#](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/320727/how-to-use-the-icomparable-and-icomparer-interfaces-in-visual-c) article.